# Change parent's background color when its child is clicked

Tags: android, android-widget, android-event

I have a TableRow which contains a LinearLayout, and then this LinearLayout contains a TextView. What I want is, once the TextView is clicked, the entire TableRow would change its background color.

I've tried to use getParent() and performClick() to pass the click event from TextView to TableRow. The onClick() method of TableRow does get called, but its background color does not change.

Of course I've set the selector by using either

```
row.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.menu_item_bgcolor);
```

or

```
row.setBackgroundDrawable(activity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.menu_item_bgcolor));
```

Doesn't work. Can anyone provide any insight into this? Thanks,

Below is the selector xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/menu_item_pressed" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/menu_item_pressed" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/menu_item_normal" />

</selector>
```

Comment: can you paste your complete xml file

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

 <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/menu_item_pressed" />
 <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/menu_item_pressed" />
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/menu_item_normal" />

</selector>

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
StateListDrawable states = new StateListDrawable();
states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_pressed},
    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pressed));
states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_focused},
    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.focused));
states.addState(new int[] { },
    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.normal));
row.setImageDrawable(states);
```

Comment: I change setImageDrawable() to setBackgroundDrawable() because setImageDrawable() does not exist on TableRow. When I click the TableRow, it will change color. But When I click the TextView, the TableRow does not change color. I still can't get this...